# Why is modifier keys on keydown delayed in "input"?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Have added a routine that show labels with access-keys when user press <kbd>Shift + Alt</kbd>.

At first I tested to see if:

```
evt.altKey && evt.shiftKey && 
  (evt.key == Shift || evt.key == Meta)
```

But this does not work on (at least) some input fields as the `shiftKey` and `altKey` is not set until **after** / on next key press. It works on for example `input type="range"` but not `type="number"` or some sort of text in general I guess.

Easy enough to fix, but curious as to *why* it is this way.

- Is it undefined behavior (I.e. can be either or)?
- Is there some definition on this behavior?

I'm on Firefox Developer Edition 93.0b9 (64-bit) - Linux.

<sup>*(Event also say `key` = "Meta" on alt key-press, but set `altKey` instead of `metaKey`, pressing meta (Windows-key) say "OS" and `metaKey` not set – but that is another question. The latter as `metaKey` not set when using meta [is "documented" on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/metaKey))*</sup>

#### Sample

Below is a simple example to run a test:

```js
const can = document.getElementById('can');
const show = e => {
  let k = [];
  if (e.shiftKey)
    k.push('Shift');
  if (e.altKey)
    k.push('Alt');
  can.textContent = 
    'modifiers(' + k.join(' + ') + ') key: ' + e.key;
};
window.addEventListener('keydown', show);
```

```css
:focus {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p id="can">&nbsp;</p>
<button>Dummy</button>
<input />
```

Say we do two test:

- Test 1 - Focus on button (or document)
- Test 2 - Focus on input

And press:

1. Press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>
2. Press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>
3. Press and release <kbd>A</kbd>
4. Press and release <kbd>X</kbd>
5. Release <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>

#### Result:

##### Test 1:

1. `modifiers(Shift) key: Shift`
2. `modifiers(Shift + Alt) key: Meta`
3. `modifiers(Shift + Alt) key: A`
4. `modifiers(Shift + Alt) key: X`

##### Test 2:

1. `modifiers() key: Shift`
2. `modifiers(Shift) key: Meta`
3. `modifiers(Shift + Alt) key: A`
4. `modifiers(Shift + Alt) key: X`